# error 2005 (hy000) unknown mysql server host (110)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy con un problema, el muy repetido error 2005.

Puedo acceder mediante el navegador a una base de datos en un servidor remoto mediante una `URL` pero cuando ejecuto el comando en la `shell` de linux tira ese error.

Esta sentencia uso:

```
mysql -h (www.blablabla) -u (usuario) -p
```

Comment: En donde se encuentra alojado el servidor?

Comment: el error parece indicar que no te esta resolviendo el host el linux desde el que estas ejecutando el mysql -h, podrias probar con la direccion IP del servidor de mysql en vez de su host(www.blablabla)

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que el servidor remoto acepte conexiones remotas y que el usuario tenga privilegios para acceder desde un IP diferente?

Comment: la primera prueba que debes hacer es un `ping www.blablabla` si te responde entonces es un problema de mysql si no es una regla de seguridad o es otra ip

Comment: la base esta alojada en un servidor remoto fuera de la lan. Tengo acceso por navegador mediante phpmyadmin. osea si pongo la direccion "10.24.5.2/phpmyadmin" tengo acceso. Si hago ping a la primera parte(10.24.5.2), tengo ping, pero a la direccion completa (con /phpmyadmin) no tengo ping.

Comment: Una cosa es entrar vía web y otra por el puerto de MySQL. Seguro es que no hay permisos para que te conectes remoto

Comment: hay alguna manera de automatizar un dump de la base con permiso web.=?

Comment: @LukasGioria, intenta hacerlo así `mysql --host=10.24.5.2 --port=13306 --user=usuario --password=contrasena`. Debes tener muy en cuenta que no es lo mismo acceder via `shell` que via `web` y además que `phpMyAdmin` es un software que se conecta al servicio `mysql`

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!